# Fetch a property file content from GCP VM using JAVA

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform

I have a properties file in GCP VM. I want to compare the content of that file with a default template that I have in my local machine. Is there a way to do it in Java where I can login to GCP VM using a Java code and fetch the property files' content and then do a comparison.
Have checked over the internet but no documentation on login to GCP VM using Java.

Comment: Is it one time activity or you want to schedule to run on intervals?

Comment: It is a one time activity.

Comment: Just download the file from VM to your local and do the comparison

Comment: @RathishKumarB the comparison has to be done at runtime. There is an automation script that we run which should do a precheck of the property file content. Manually downloading the file will not be a viable solution.

Comment: added one solution, check if this works for your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [Cloud Storage Fuse](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse)

[Install](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/installing.md) and [mount Cloud Storage bucket](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md) to your VM. Now you can access your Cloud Storage bucket as regular filesystem in VM.

Keep the property file in Cloud Storage bucket and do the required comparison through script.

This way, file is accessible to automation script ([Java Client library for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java)) as well as the application running on VM as local file.